# How to use NSNotificationCenter to send a notification from one UIButton to another UIButton

Tags: iphone

How this UIButton rewind can send notification to UIButton play to perform playpauseaction method when rewind button is clicked.

```
-(void)rewind:(id)sender{
[timer invalidate]; 
audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
MainViewController *viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[viewController release];
} 

 -(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender {    
if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [audioPlayer pause];
    [self pauseTimer];
    [self pauseLayer:self.view.layer];
}
else
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audioPlayer play];
    [self resumeTimer];
    [self resumeLayer:self.view.layer];

    if(isFirstTime == YES)
    {
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:NO];
        isFirstTime = NO;
    }
    }
    }
```

rewind button when clicks perform rewind method and as well send notification to play button to perform playpauseAction method.

Thanks for help.

**EDIT**
Have declared

```
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *playButton;
    @synthesize playButton = _playButton; 
   [self playpauseAction:_playButton];
```

what happening is when clicking on rewind button it performing play pause action method but not toggling play button to pause as per playpauseaction method. why is that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reference to your play pause button (which you will want to have to make this kind of thing a ton easier), you can just write this line in your `rewind` method

```
[self playpauseAction:playpauseButton];
```

You don't need to use the notification center at all

Comment: Yeah, your right, perhaps they might want to call it from another class (I don't know why they would want to do that), but I guess thats what they asked for... Your answer is much better though... ;)

Comment: how to get reference of play pause button

Comment: Create an IBOutlet property, and hook it up in interface builder, assuming of course you created the button in interface builder

Comment: that is what i was thinking do i have to hook it up in interface builder but what if i am not using interface builder at all. Doing all programmtically

Comment: Then simply store the button that you created programmatically in a member ivar or property at the point that you create it

Comment: please check my answer if that is what you are saying then it is not working

Comment: You've made the property, but you haven't set it to anything.  When you're creating the button (`[[UIButton alloc] init....]`) you need to assign it to the playButton property

Comment: please can you tell me how i can assign to playButton property  UIButton *playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playpauseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
playButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
[playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];UIBarButtonItem *play = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:playButton];

Comment: instead of `UIButton *playButton = [UIButton...]` try `self.playButton = [UIButton...]`

Comment: it worked. Thankyou so much for all your help and time. Appreciate so much.

Answer (score 2):

In your view did load write this;

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playpauseAction) name:@"ButtonPressed" object:nil];
```

When the button is pressed add this code;

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ButtonPressed" object:nil];
```

And it should call your playpauseAction.

Don't forget in your dealloc to write;

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"ButtonPressed" object:nil];
```

Otherwise you code will crash, as the method will still try to be called even when the instance of you class no longer exists.

Hope this helps,

Jonathan

Comment: so basically in the rewind method i should add this [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ButtonPressed" object:nil]; to send notification play button to perform playpauseaction method right

Comment: In dealloc method added [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil]; and got message in red that use of undeclared identifier kReachabilityChangedNotification

Comment: Whoops, sorry edited the code - should be right now! And in response to your first comment, yes, you are correct.

Comment: now after adding the notificationstatement in the rewind method when click the rewind button app crash and message is this [NSConcreteNotification setImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155e70'